# Changing select value dynamically

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am new to angular 6 and trying to populate a select field using reactive forms,

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <select id="estimated-volume" [formControlName]="'usage'">
        <option [value]="null">Usage</option>
        <option *ngFor="let option of availableBounds" [ngValue]="option">
            {{option.lower_bound}}-{{option.upper_bound}}
        </option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Here Usage is default value, and the angular code is

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
      'usage': new FormControl(null, Validators.nullValidator),
    }
);
availableBounds = [
    {
       lower_bound: 0,
       upper_bound: 1000,
       value: 5
    },
    {
       lower_bound: 50000,
       upper_bound: 10000,
       value: 50
    }
]
```

Upto here everything is working fine, Now after an api call I am getting a response in which I have to populate this select with other object according to api, hence I am trying to do something like this.

```
response = {
               lower_bound: 2,
               upper_bound: 5,
               value: 5
           };

this.form.controls['usage'].setValue(response, {onlySelf: true});
```

But this is not able to set a value for the select box, any suggestions for the alternate method? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you simply empty availableBounds and reassign it with newly received object?

Comment: `availableBounds` is array of object and `response` is object. Empty  `availableBounds` and push response if it is single object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to push the api response into the existing array and then after set the value to formCOntrol

like this,

```
constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      usage: ''
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let response = {
      lower_bound: 2,
      upper_bound: 5,
      value: 5
    };

    this.availableBounds.push(response);

    this.form.get('usage').setValue(response, { onlySelf: true });
  }
```

here is [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b7xshm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) demo

Comment: generally you has a FIXED list of availableBounds

Answer (score 2):

`availableBounds` is array of object and `response` is object. Do empty `availableBounds` and push `response` to it. This will set a value for the select box also.

```js
var availableBounds = [
    {
       lower_bound: 0,
       upper_bound: 1000,
       value: 5
    },
    {
       lower_bound: 50000,
       upper_bound: 10000,
       value: 50
    }
];

console.log(availableBounds); 

var response = {
               lower_bound: 2,
               upper_bound: 5,
               value: 5
           };
           
availableBounds.length = 0;
availableBounds.push(response);
console.log(availableBounds);
```

Comment: Please do not post code-only answers. They are not very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Try  to push **response** object in **availableBounds** array because ngFor only work with array.

**availableBounds.push(response);**

Answer (score 1):

if your [ngValue]="option" is an object, you need equal to an object. So

```
//I supouse  you has a service that has a return httpClient.get(....)
myService.getValues().subscribe(res=>
   //imagine res={value:50}
{
  let select=this.availableBounds.find(a=>a.value==res.value)
  this.form = this.fb.group({
      usage: select || null  //<--the object itself or null
    })
});
```

You can use set value in two steps too

```
  let select=this.availableBounds.find(a=>a.value==5)
  this.form.get('usage').setValue(select || null);
```